# Why my values are undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have made a game like Word chain. I have an array which contains names of cities.

If I open the page, the user can see one random letter and input box with button.

He must enter the city with the same letter. But now I have errors and undefined values.

I have start letter which I see if I open that page:

```
    var rand = generateRandom(rand);
    LettersDiv.innerHTML = ab[rand];
```

And i have function which called when I click on the button:

```
 function turnRound(e,myUser, myBot){
        var myChoise;
        myChoise = document.getElementById("city").value; //input box
        var botData = searchWord(ab[rand]); //city in array
        ab.splice(rand, 1); //alphabeta
        if(botData !== null) resultDiv.innerHTML += botData + '<br>';
        if(myChoise !== null) resultDiv.innerHTML += myChoise + '<br>';
        var rand = generateRandom(rand);
        LettersDiv.innerHTML = ab[rand];
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

but botData has 0 value not city. What to do?

full code: https://plnkr.co/edit/NN8XnORn45CIx4XT6HNd?p=preview

```js
var city_str = "Абаза,Абакан,Абдулино,Абинск,Агидель,Агрыз,Адыгейск,Азнакаево,Азов,Аксай,Алагир,Алапаевск,Алатырь,Алдан,Алейск,Александров,Аша,Бабаево,Бабушкин,Бавлы,Багратионовск,Байкальск,Баймак,Бакал,Баксан,Балабаново,Балаково,Балахна,Балашиха,Балашов,Балей,Балтийск,Барабинск,Барнаул,Барыш,Батайск,Бахчисарай,Бежецк,БелаяКалитва,БелаяХолуница,Белгород,Белебей,Белинский,Белово,Белогорск,Белогорск,Белозерск,Белокуриха,Беломорск,Белорецк,Белореченск,Белоусово,Борисоглебск,Боровичи,Боровск,Бородино,Братск,Бронницы,Брянск,Бугульма,Бугуруслан,Будённовск,Буинск,Буй,Бутурлиновка,Валдай,Валуйки,ВеликиеЛуки,ВеликийНовгород,ВеликийУстюг,Венёв,Верещагино,Верхнеуральск,ВерхнийТагил,ВерхнийУфалей,Владивосток,Владикавказ,Владимир,Волгоград,Волгодонск,Воркута,Воронеж,Ворсма,Воскресенск,Воткинск,Всеволожск,Вуктыл,Выборг,Выкса,Высоковск,Высоцк,Вытегра,Вяземский,Вязники,Вязьма,ВятскиеПоляны";
var city = city_str.split(',');

var ab = ["А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Д", "Е", "Ж", "З", "И", "Й", "К", "Л", "М", "Н", "О", "П", "Р", "С", "Т"];

var LettersDiv = document.getElementById('letter');
var resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');
var playBtn = document.getElementById('play');

if (document.getElementById('myForm')) {
  document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', turnRound, false);
}


function user(countCity, countRiver, count) {
  this.countCity = countCity;
  this.countRiver = countRiver;
  this.count = countCity;
}


function searchWord(letter) {
  //letter = letter.toUpperCase();
  return city.find(n => n[0] == letter) || 0;
}

function generateRandom(rand) {
  if (rand >= ab.length) return rand = ab.length
  else
    return rand = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (ab.length));

}

var rand = generateRandom(rand);
LettersDiv.innerHTML = ab[rand];

function turnRound(e, myUser, myBot) {
  var myChoise;
  myChoise = document.getElementById("city").value;


  //LettersDiv.innerHTML = ab[rand];

  alert(rand);

  var botData = searchWord(ab[rand]);

  ab.splice(rand, 1);

  if (botData !== null) resultDiv.innerHTML += botData + '<br>';
  if (myChoise !== null) resultDiv.innerHTML += myChoise + '<br>';


  //

  var rand = generateRandom(rand);
  LettersDiv.innerHTML = ab[rand];


  /* if (myChoise == botData) {
       myUser.countCity += 5;
       myBot.countCity += 5;
   }
   else if (myChoise != botData) {
       myUser.countCity += 10;
       myBot.countCity += 10;
   }
   else if (trim(myChoise) == '') {
       myBot.countCity += 15;
   }
   else myUser.countUser += 15; */


  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div id="letter"></div>
  <input type="text" value="" id="city">
  <button type="submit" id="play">Submit</button>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Start by  console.log(letter,city)

Comment: undefined and 0

Comment: You even alert(rand) which is undefined too so what would (ab[rand] be

Comment: `function generateRandom(num) {
  if (num >= ab.length)  return ab.length;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ab.length));
}
rand = generateRandom(5);`  would likely work better

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, variables `rand` is used before it declared in function,  if the Variables is declared in the function, no matter the declare statement in which place of function, it will ignore declarations outside of function scope, so it isn't assigned when it called first.

`hoisting`
  - Hoisting is a JavaScript mechanism where variables and function declarations are moved to the top of their scope before code execution.

reference [Variable hoisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Declaration_and_assignment)

try

```
function turnRound(e,myUser, myBot){
        var myChoise;
        var rand = generateRandom();
        myChoise = document.getElementById("city").value; //input box
        var botData = searchWord(ab[rand]); //city in array
        LettersDiv.innerHTML = ab[rand];
        ab.splice(rand, 1); //alphabeta
        if(botData !== null) resultDiv.innerHTML += botData + '<br>';
        if(myChoise !== null) resultDiv.innerHTML += myChoise + '<br>';
        rand = generateRandom(rand);
        LettersDiv.innerHTML = ab[rand];
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Your explanation was correct, Your execution wrong: `var rand = generateRandom(rand);`

Comment: tks, we can simply use `undefined` as first execution param.